# Google Maps not rendering correctly in modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a problem when loading google maps inside a modal window. Basically when the modal window is opened I load the map, but it doesn't render completely.

I'm including an  example so you can understand the problem better. Does someone know how to fix this?

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#link").colorbox({
                inline:true, 
                width:"50%", 
                onOpen: function(){
                    $('#cboxClose').remove();
                    var script = document.createElement("script");
                        script.type = "text/javascript";
                        script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=showMapsStep1";
                        document.body.appendChild(script);
                }
            });


            window.showMapsStep1 = function(){


                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("canvas"), mapOptions);

                $('#canvas').show();
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#box" id="link">Open modal <a/>

    <div style='display:none'>
        <div id='box' style='height: 300px; width: 500px;' >
            <div id="canvas" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT:
This was tested on google chrome.
If I resize the window the map is rendered correctly

Comment: I've had issues with google maps if height and width are not set to pixel values.  Try that since you're just using 100% anyways

Comment: Do you have an working example also try a zoom: 1, and see if this will work after that you can try zooming in some more again

Comment: @NuclearGhost In my code (not this example) I define height and width by pixels and that doesn't fix the problem

Comment: @IvoJonkers That doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I did some more tests and I think it has something to do with gmaps not being able to retrieve height and width values when the element is hidden, since if I set a timeout to draw the map, so it's drawn after the modal is opened then it renders fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grey boxes appear in parts of embedded Google Map in modal box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812268/grey-boxes-appear-in-parts-of-embedded-google-map-in-modal-box)

Comment: @geocodezip Yep, same problem, Didn't find it in my first search, srry

Comment: Anyway, I figured it out the solution. The problem was that I was trying to load the map before the modal finish displaying, so I used another callback (onComplete) and it works fine now

Comment: I know you asked for burgers but what about pizza (fancybox)? http://jsfiddle.net/8QQY5/ (works even with IE7+)

Answer (score 0):

You have to trigger 'resize' map event.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("canvas"), mapOptions);

google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize', function () {
    // your callback content
});
```