# Show Map on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, google-api

I want to show a new google map on a bootstrap modal but it doesnt seem to work. please help

```js
$scope.show = function (lat, long) {
        $('#body').append('<div id="map"></div>')
        enter code here$scope.newMap=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: {lat: 37.77, lng: -122.447},
            mapTypeId:'roadmap'
        });
```

Comment: are you sure `$('#body')` point's on modal-content node? and i think you have to use `$(modalSelector).on('show.bs.modal' function(){ ... })` as listener to hear on modal open event

Comment: I tried it. didnt work.   $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
            $('#body').append('<div id="map"></div>')
            $scope.newMap=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 14,
                center: {lat: 37.77, lng: -122.447},
                mapTypeId:'roadmap'
            });
        })

Comment: I'll advise using the angular-bootstrap modal. Implemented with angular in mind:  https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not my code but here's a working example of what you want - [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/JetUBY/)

This example uses the module 'ngMap' which has the directive 'map',
For more you can see the [ngMap](https://ngmap.github.io/) home page.