# angular-google-maps directive refresh not working

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm using this library (http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api) to show a bootstrap modal containing a map.  Since the modal is hidden Google maps doesn't know exactly how scale the map and hence I'm only getting a partial map like so: http://s21.postimg.org/okifi7bk7/Screen_Shot_2014_12_25_at_12_21_58_PM.png

I have the refresh attr set to a flag var but that doesn't seem to work

Any pointers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google map modal issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732427/google-map-modal-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching to the tilesloaded event and triggering a resize on the map. Some google searches for map partial render should turn up other options as well. [Google map modal issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732427/google-map-modal-issue)