# Google map marker not displayed center in Modal pop up

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm using the code below to display a Google Map on modal pop-up. But the Google Map marker is not displayed at the center of the modal. It's always hidden at the left corner.

[image: Map image]

```
<script>
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  }


  function codeAddress(i) {       

    var address = document.getElementById('address'+i).value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            zoom:10,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });

        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        });

        } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });

  }   

 </script>
```

Also [see the code here](https://olez.com/map.js)

Comment: Easier with a sample page :) First, their is no use of your LatLng var. Remove it (or use it :)) From what I understand, the map redraw is invoked when map is idle. Are you sure the idle event is fired?

Comment: I'm getting LatLng from my variables dynamically. Its working good. I also see the marker. Issue was it shows left corner.How do i move this one to center of map? Please help

Comment: Does a manual map.setCenter(latLng) solve your issue? If yes, it means your map center is not well used by gmap. In this case, just set your map center after the redraw.

Comment: How to set map center after the redraw. Could you please modify and explain with code i sent. I'm very newbie here.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be related to [Google map modal issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732427/google-map-modal-issue).

Please try using the modal event handlers as given [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27187771) by @SSR:

> Bootstrap Modal Map Issue Solution :
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>   $('#locationMap').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
>     google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
>     map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195));
>   });
> });
> ```

Solution in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11848500) might also help.