# Google map cut inside bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3, modal-dialog

This problem is bugging me for few days now. I almost gave up when yesterday I accidentally discovered something. 
I'm using Google map inside bootstrap modal. Problem is when I  call modal, map is cut in half and I can pan and zoom it in the half of div, but strange thing is that when I turn on inspector(in any browser) entire map is shown right away and everything works like it should. Anyone had similar problem?

On calling modal:

[image]

After calling inspector:

[image]

Comment: Your map doesn't have a size. Lots of questions about this problem with modals in bootstrap.

Comment: Thx, don't know why I assumed I was first with this problem.

Comment: Specifically this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11848500/863487 - will solve your problem