# How to render maps within ng-hide divs using ngMap without getting a gray rectangle

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide, ng-map

The problem: Google Maps elements that are within divs that are initially 
rendered as ng-hidden come up as gray rectangles when they are ng-shown.

I've put together this Plunker to demonstrate: https://plnkr.co/edit/emzlIT?p=preview

Others have had success using `google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize')`, but for 
me it is no help, perhaps because I have multiple maps hidden. On this plunker, 
`'resize'` seems to make a difference, but not consistently. *If you play with 
the Plunker and everything seems to be working, try panning around an ng-shown 
map and you'll get the gray.*

The example shown is, of course, a very simplified version of the actual web-app I'm working on. 
Suffice it to say that using `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` (also worked for others) isn't an option, nor is
having my maps always shown (though if no solutions are found, I may have to think
outside the div.)

Note: if you get a grayed out map, **zooming the browser in or out seems to 
jump-start the render & then the maps work perfectly**, even if hidden and re-shown I don't know what about the 
browser zoom triggers the desired behavior, but perhaps that's a clue to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is most likely related with `ng-hide` directive which in turn adds `display: none` style on the parent element. It was already reported ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812268/grey-boxes-appear-in-parts-of-embedded-google-map-in-modal-box)) that Google Maps control has some issues with rendering once the map is located inside the element that has `display: none` style.

I would suggest to replace `ng-hide` directive:

```
<div ng-hide="div1Hide" class="mapCase">
    <ng-map id="map1" class="map" center="[-33.851371, 151.277736]" zoom-level="18">Parsley</ng-map>
</div>
```

with, for example, `ng-class` directive:

```
<div class="mapCase" ng-style="{'visibility': !div1Hide ? 'visible':'hidden'}">
     <ng-map id="map1" class="map" center="[-33.851371, 151.277736]" zoom-level="18">Parsley</ng-map>
</div>
```

[**Modified plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/bYiy2m)

Comment: This is a good solution, though for my actual code, I'm using dynamically created "hide-codes" which are properly bound with ng-hide, but not ng-style, so it doesn't work for me. Grr.