# How to replace the (path to kml) into variable ? I'm using geoxml3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, kml, geoxml3

**How to replace myParser.parse('*path/to/data.kml*') into variable that contain kml file like this.**
https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3

```
var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: map});
myParser.parse('/path/to/data.kml');
```

Like this:

```
  var result = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ... </kml>'"
  var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: map});
  myParser.parse(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`geoXML3` library](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) contains [`parseKmlString` function](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/blob/master/polys/geoxml3.js#L103) to parse KML from a string.

Example

```js
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: {lat: 31.40065516914794, lng: -98.30505371484378}
    });
  
    
    var parser = new geoXML3.parser({map: map});
    parser.parseKmlString('<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><Document><Placemark><name><![CDATA[]]>Polygon</name><description><![CDATA[]]></description><Polygon><extrude>1</extrude><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-93.46008301171878,31.329035778926478,0 -98.30505371484378,31.40065516914794,0 -97.37121582421878,30.106233605369603,0 -92.65808105859378,30.14749530904506,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs> </Polygon></Placemark></Document></kml>'); 
  }


  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
#map {
        height: 140px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/geocodezip/geoxml3/master/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: sir @vadim gremyachev, sir can i ask you one last time regarding to your answer here in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886358/how-to-render-maps-within-ng-hide-divs-using-ngmap-without-getting-a-gray-rectan..  what if i want to use display:none? is it possible?

Comment: Hello @Paulo, unfortunately the hiding the map with `display:none` does not work properly, instead i would suggest to use `visibility: hidden`

Comment: sir @Vadim can i ask you again? <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>  should i download this header that needs in geoxml? and add to my project. or leave it as is?.

Comment: is it ok to download this header to my project? or will i have a problem in the future if i download this? and use this this forever.? sorry my english is bad.

Comment: I would suggest to keep a reference to Google Maps library via 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js' , downloading it could be problematic since it has a dependency to  additional packages behind the scene