# Angular- Display google map inside specific id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to show Google map inside specific container in ui-booststrap modal using **Angularjs**. Here is my code :

**HTML :**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="mapModalContent.html">
    <div class="map-container" ng-class="{'open' : openMapContainer}">
        <div class="header-section">
        header
        </div>
        <div class="close-btn"><i class="icon icon-cancel"></i></div>
        <div id="map-test" class="map-test"></div>
        <div id="map-content"></div>
        <div class="footer-section"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

**Angular:**

```
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'mapModalContent.html',
        scope: $scope,
        windowClass: 'mapModal',
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {
            data: function () {
                return $scope;
            }
        }
    });
        modalInstance.opened.then(function() {
            console.log('opened');
        });
    }
    $scope.$watch('data', function(value){
        if(typeof value !== 'undefined') {
            searchLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.data.latitude, $scope.data.longitude);

             googleMap = new google.maps.Map($element.find('.map-content'), {
                 center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                 zoom: 8
             });
            searchMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: searchLatLng,
                map: googleMap,
                draggable: true
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(searchMarker, 'dragend', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.data.latitude = searchMarker.getPosition().lat();
                    $scope.data.longitude = searchMarker.getPosition().lng();
                });
            }.bind(this));

            var myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.data.latitude, $scope.data.longitude);
            searchMarker.setPosition(myPosition);
        }
    }, true);
}
```

In console , I get

*opened* (for opening modal)

and

[image]

Actually , map doesn't load yet. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, there is a gray box.

Can you try this:

```
modalInstance.opened.then(function() {
    console.log('opened');
     google.maps.event.trigger(googleMap, "resize");
});
```

[Grey boxes appear in parts of embedded Google Map in modal box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812268/grey-boxes-appear-in-parts-of-embedded-google-map-in-modal-box)